# What are the data type(s) whose element indices can be accessed using source characters other than digits/integers?

Tags: python, syntax

```
print("{[a]}".format("hello world!"))
```

The code results in: "TypeError: string indices must be integers". I would like to know the data type(s) whose element indices can be accessed using source characters other than digits/integers. In other words, I want to understand the definition/syntax of 'index_string' in the [replacement field grammar demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlXqt.png) of the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Thank you!

Comment: ...question is unclear: you could write your own custom data types (classes) that would accept a str to access contained elements. an example of a _built in_ data type would be ```dict```...

Comment: I was asking if there is a data type that I can put as an argument to format() in the code above whose element indices I can specify using non-digit source characters, like [a] (not a string like ["a"]), because the [replacement field grammar demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlXqt.png) of the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) seems to suggest that there is.